# Sorted linked list implementation

Tags: java

i am a novice programmer, to be specific, i am learning java programming and i am supposed to implement sortedLinkedList class that extends LinkedList class from the java library. The list has to store persons in ascending order of their surnames. I have already written my Person class that implements Comparable interface. my problem is, I have been struggling implementing this sortedLinkedClass but to no avail. My code runs without any compiling or run time error but the program does not print anything. Another thing as you can see , I am testing it with Integers instead of Persons and it throws NullPointerException when trying to add a number that is already in the list. My code is as it is below.

```
import java.util.*;
public class SortedLinkedList< E> extends LinkedList<E> 
{
   private Link<E> first;
   private Link<E> last;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class SortedLinkedList
 */
public SortedLinkedList()
{
    //super();
    first = null;
    last = null;

}

/*
 * Link class for creating Link nodes in the SortedLinkedList objects
 */
private class Link<E> 
{
    public Comparable<E> data;
    public Link next;

}
/*
 * Overiding add method from LinkedList class
 */
public boolean add(E obj)
{
    Link newLink = new Link();
    newLink.data = (Comparable<E>)obj;

    // When the list is initially empty
    if (first == null)
    {
        first = newLink;
        last = newLink;
        return true;
    }


    // When the element to be added is less than the first element in the list
    if (newLink.data.compareTo(first.data) < 0)
    {
        //newLink.data = obj;
        newLink.next = first;
        first = newLink;
        return true;
    }

    // When the element to be added is greater than every element in in list
    // and has to be added at end of the list
    if (newLink.data.compareTo(last.data) > 0)
    {
        //newLink.data = obj;
        last.next = newLink;
        last = newLink;
        return true;
    }

    //When the element to be added lies between other elements in the list
    if (newLink.data.compareTo(first.data) >= 0 && newLink.data.compareTo(last.data) <= 0)
    {
        //newLink.data = obj;
        Link current = first.next;
        Link previous = first;
        while (newLink.data.compareTo(current.data) <= 0)
        {
           previous = current;
           current = current.next;
        }
        previous.next = newLink;
        newLink.next = current;

    }

    return true;
}


public static void main (String[] args)
{
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new SortedLinkedList<Integer>();
    list.add(4);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(10);
    list.add(9);
    //list.add(5);
    ListIterator<Integer> iterator = list.listIterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
         System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }


}
```

}

Comment: As to the crash when adding duplicate values: have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: You should tell your teacher that this task is really stupid. There is no way to implement such a subclass without breaking the contract of the superclass and interfaces. For example, addFirst is supposed to add some elemant at the first position. what if the element to insert is larger than the current first one? This is really not good OO practice.

Answer (score 5):

If you must use a LinkedList, all you really have to do is override the "add" method so that it inserts your element in the correct position. You can do that by invoking the add(integer,Object) method which inserts your element in a specific position.

Here's a quick and dirty (and non-generic :P) implementation of what I'm talking about.

```
public class PersonLinkedList extends LinkedList<Person> {

    public boolean add(Person personToAdd) {
        int index = 0;
        for( ; index<size() ; index++){
            Person personAlreadyInList = get(index);

            if(personToAdd.compareTo(personAlreadyInList) < 0){
                break;
            }
        }

        add(index, personToAdd);
        return true;
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person amy = new Person("Amy");
        Person bob = new Person("Bob");
        Person claire = new Person("Claire");

        PersonLinkedList list = new PersonLinkedList();
        list.add(bob);
        list.add(claire);
        list.add(claire);
        list.add(amy);
        list.add(bob);

        for (Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Person person = (Person) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(person);
        }
    }
}

class Person implements Comparable<Person>{

    private String name;

    public Person(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return getName();}

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person p) {
        return name.compareTo(p.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should never use get with a LinkedList, using an iterator would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The reason nothing gets printed is because you store the data in your own linked list data tree and not the LinkedList's data tree.  You don't override the iterator method, so the iterator will loop through LinkedList's data which is empty.  This is also a problem with all the other methods in LinkedList.

Are you sure you need to inherit from the LinkedList class or are you suppose to make your own class.

If you are supposed to inherit from LinkedList get rid of you node and use LinkedList for storing the data.  Your add method would then use a ListIterator to find the correct spot for adding and use the add method of ListIterator.

If you don't inherit from LinkedList then extend AbstractSequentialList.

Note:

Both of these options should not be used in real code.  Adding automatic sorting breaks the List interface.

The whole problem is a perfect example of "prefer composition over inheritance".

If this is homework do it as instructed, otherwise I'd recommend changing the exercise to implement a SortedCollection backed by a LinkedList.  Then implement Collection and use a List as a member variable.

Comment: Better yet, extend `AbstractSequentialList`, [its documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSequentialList.html) explicitly points out which methods you have to implement to get the others "for free". (Which is mostly `listIterator` and the methods in your `ListIterator` subclass.

Comment: @Inerdia Updated with your recommendation

Comment: @Michael, thanx so much. Actually one of the specification is to inherit Linkedlist. But after getting rid of the nodes and make use of LinkedList class now I can get everything sorted and printed. The only problem I had is the add() method of Listiterator only appends elements at the end of the list. So I had to use for loop and get() and add(index, e) methods for inserting element in the middle of the list. I know you said this is not the efficient way but for the timebeing at list I have something that works, next I will try it again with ListIterator.

Comment: @ally The ListIterator.add should add the new element after the element returned by the last call to next().  So you would loop through the list, like you did with get(), but using the iterator instead, once you found the correct place stop looping and call add.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [SortedSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) if you don't need to support elements with the same sort key.

Also, the reason your code doesn't print anything is because you override adding items to the list, but not iterating (the `iterator()` or `listIterator()` methods.) Extending `LinkedList` doesn't automagically make your data structure iterable unless you modify its contents using the base class `add()`, `remove()`, and other methods.

Comment: `LinkedList` implements `Iterable`, so extending it makes a data structure iterable too

Comment: @fortran What I meant was: extending `LinkedList` does not give your completely custom data structure correct iteration behaviour. Not "iterable" as in "can produce an `Iterator` no matter how useless".

Comment: In fact it does, `LinkedList` is a data structure ready to use. I suggest you to take a quick look to the API http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html because maybe you are confusing it with some template-like class as `AbstractList` (that also provides correct iteration, by the way!). The problem is that the op was adding its elements elsewhere, so when getting them the list is always empty, no matter how many times the overridden `add` was called.

Comment: @fortran "The problem is that the op was adding its elements elsewhere, so when getting them the list is always empty, no matter how many times the overridden `add` was called." – that's exactly what I said in my answer?

Comment: Oh, you are right, I must have been so obfuscated when I first read your answer that my brain stopped processing after the second sentence xD

Answer (score 0):

besides `iterator, add/remove` override, I think your algorithm to sort is not correct. And that leads to the nullpointer exception when you add existing elements into your "sortedLinkedList".

```
 while (newLink.data.compareTo(current.data) <= 0)
        {
           previous = current;
           current = current.next;
        }
```

I think what you wanted is `while (newLink.data.compareTo(current.data) >0)` . not `<=0`. here is the mistake.

since "=0" is in while condition, it will go through the whole list, till the last element, then execute:

```
(current is the last now)
    previous = current;
    current = current.next; (now, current is Null, since last.next is Null)
```

finally, current is Null, then comes again, current = current.next; Bang! Nullpointer.

so I guess the Nullpointer was thrown at this line.

Comment: thanx, no more exception but I am still trying to get it priting.